# Free Delphi compiler

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is there a free official Delphi 2010 compiler available for download? I have visited embarcadero's website but only see versions that cost $1500+.

Comment: Is pascal the same as Delphi?

Comment: Delphi is based on the Pascal language, but Pascal is not Delphi.  The FreePascal compiler (http://www.freepascal.org) implements its own interpretation of the Pascal language, and offers a Delphi compatibility mode for people switching from Delphi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no free versions of the 2010 compiler available.

Answer (score 16):

You can also test [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/).

Comment: "Lazarus is a Delphi compatible cross-platform IDE"

I know that it also offers UI development but does it also offer a compiler?

Answer (score 4):

Embarcadero just announced new editions of Delphi and C++Builder for $199 each:

[Embarcadero Introduces Starter Editions of C++Builder and Delphi Rapid Application Development Environments](http://www.sdtimes.com/link/35223)

---

**Update**: Embarcadero has recently announced Community editions of Delphi and C++Builder that are free-of-charge:

[Introducing Delphi and C++Builder Community Edition](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/introducing-delphi-cplusplusbuilder-community-edition)